# varnish service is restarting after few hours

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am running varnish 4.1.11 version as a pod with default malloc to 60% of memory limit and observing that varnish service is consuming all memory and restart once reach 100% memory.

varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a:8080 -s default=malloc,2744m -t 120 -p nuke_limit=2000

logs

```
Log reacquired
Error: Unexpected reply from ping: 400 CLI communication error (hdr)
Error: Child (186905) not responding to CLI, killed it.
Log abandoned
Error: Child (186905) died signal=9
Debug: Child cleanup complete
```

I am feeling it not respecting nuke_limit and  n_lru_nuked metrics is 0.
Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

I started with 4.1.8 and upgraded to 4.1.11 still same issue

Expected is it should nuke the memory and should not restart service but actually it restarting and I am losing all cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please check either varnishlog or run the command `varnishadm panic.show` so that we can see why Varnish is crashing(might not be the nuke limit)

Comment: I  verified varnishadm panic.show:
`
varnish> panic.show
300        
Child has not panicked or panic has been cleared
`
there is no panic we have two malloc allocations 77% and 3% of memory

Comment: what if you look for either "kill" or "die" in the dmesg? Anything in there? My lucky guess is that Varnish hasn't enough memory and it crashes?
Also, ho many Transient obj do you have? (you can find this in varnishstat)

Answer (score 0):

The child was unresponsive, is you `/var/lib/varnish` mounted as tmp? This is where the logs are , and varnish write **A LOT**, if it does so on disk, you may get that sort of result